# How do I make all window corners to be rounded?

Tags: themes, gala, design, macintosh

In the macOS the all the four window corners are rounded, like the image below:

[image: Safari on macOS Sierra with window corners rounded]

But in eOS, the windows corners are usually like this:
[image: Files app in eOS with only two of the corners rounded]

Here only two of the four corners of the window are rounded. I don't know if it is just me, but the windows rounded feel more comfortable to my eyes, like the screen corners are.

I've searched a bit and did not found any way to do or enable windows to be rendered like this. I saw that Mail app renders it's welcome screen with corners rounded.

There's any way to enable this? If no, what is the best approach to propose this to the design team?

Comment: I'm guessing there are themes which have this visual property, probably achieved by transparency.

Comment: They did it for default music player application (noise) only. And yeah, it looks a bit nicer.

Comment: Looks like eOS 6 will have that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In what looks like a forward-looking change according to [issue #5](https://github.com/elementary/stylesheet/issues/5) on the stylesheet's GitHub repo, apps have to request the rounded corners via a class in elementary's GTK+ stylesheet. See [pull request #20](https://github.com/elementary/stylesheet/pull/20) for the relevant code. I'm not sure the apps have caught up with this change, though.

There's probably a way for you to modify the stylesheet so that the apps you desire have rounded corners (check out `/usr/share/themes/elementary/gtk-3.0/app.css`), but you'd need to know the class for each app's window frame, to which you'd add a `border-radius` value -- it looks like it isn't really standardized at the moment.

Comment: Thanks! I've commented on the issue asking if that change is global.